# How to set field separators in bibtex-mode's autokey generator?

Tags: latex, bibtex

**Q:** how do I set a specific separator in `bibtex-mode`'s `autokey` generator?

#### Background

I am working
with
[`bibtex-mode`](http://www.jonathanleroux.org/bibtex-mode.html).
It has a feature
to
[auto-generate the entry key](http://www.jonathanleroux.org/bibtex-mode.html#0630),
which is customizable.

#### Goal

My goal is to get the autokey to work as follows:

- One author: authorname:year.
- Two authors: authorname1-authorname2:year.
- Three or more authors: authorname1-etal:year.

#### Almost There

The following settings *almost* get me there:

```
(setf bibtex-autokey-additional-names "etal"
      bibtex-autokey-name-separator "-"
      bibtex-autokey-name-year-separator ":"
      bibtex-autokey-year-length 4
      bibtex-autokey-names 1
      bibtex-autokey-names-stretch 1
      bibtex-autokey-titlewords 0)
```

#### The Specific Problem

It works for one and two authors.  However, for three or more
authors, the generated key is:

```
authorname1etal:year
```

rather than the desired, hyphen-separated

```
authorname1-etal:year
```

*How do I get the hyphen separator between the author name and the
etal?*

#### Examples

```
@Article{,
  author       = {Bob Smith},
  title        = {A title},
  journal      = {A journal},
  year         = 2014
}
```

produces `smith:2014`

```
@Article{,
  author       = {Bob Smith and Frank Jones},
  title        = {A title},
  journal      = {A journal},
  year         = 2015
}
```

produces `smith-jones:2015`

```
@Article{,
  author       = {Bob Smith and Frank Jones and Joe Johnson},
  title        = {A title},
  journal      = {A journal},
  year         = 2016
}
```

produces `smithetal:2016` (and I want `smith-etal:2016`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the simple, if slightly barbaric, solution of setting `bibtex-autokey-additional-names` to `"-etal"`, (with a hyphen built-in), work for you?

It has the advantage that you don't have to source-dive or modify any of the elisp functions.

Comment: Oiy, yes, that works just fine.  The autokey machinery is so intricate that I was searching around for the right nob to adjust, and it never occurred to me that there was a very simple answer available.  Thanks!